# freeze training of individual neurons in a layer and not the entire layer itself in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

So I want to train a network(particularly CNN) where only some neurons are trainable while others have fixed weights. For this I need to freeze the training of some percentage of neurons in each layer. How should I do it?

Comment: freezing an individual neuron makes little sense...

Comment: Some experiments I am conducting entail fixing the weights of a few neurons in each layer and train them

Comment: @MitchWheat I think without knowing more about what Shubham Dash tries to achive/study it is quite the assumption that freezing only some neurons makes little sense. Shubham Dash, pls provide an MCVE showing where you are stuck. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NOhs: you are correct. I'm just going by what has been published to date.

Comment: I think I found a way of doing it by creating custom keras layers and mask neuron training with the help of "self.trainable = False"